# ScriptEngineManager giving error

Tags: java

I'm using below code to evaluate some expression in Java

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String value = engine.eval(BODMAS.toString()).toString(); //eg: 2*4+9/4*4
if(value.contains("E") || value.contains("e"))
    fillValue = Integer.toString((int) Double.parseDouble(value));
else
    fillValue = value.substring(0, value.indexOf('.'));
```

And I got the below error ---

Error Message:

```
com.ibm.ws.exception.WsException: javax.script.ScriptEngineManager
at com.ibm.ws.exception.WsEJBException.getCausedByException(WsEJBException.java:143)
```

I am Using JDK 1.6, and there is no error while compiling the code.

Comment: Is that the only message in the stacktrace? If there is more info, please post it.

Comment: HTTP request headers:
 Via=1.1 TMG
 Cookie=testCookie=1; locale=en-us; JSESSIONID=0000VmDt70QfQ8jTkWpuhBWWilQ:16ltsmkhl
 Referer=http:/****ms/cdsApp?Module=Login&_pageno=3&browserWidth=1366
 User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
 Host=172.16.2.121
 Accept=text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
 Accept-Language=en-IN
 Accept-Encoding=gzip
 $WSIS=false
 $WSSC=http
 $WSPR=HTTP/1.1
 $WSRA=ip address
 $WSRH=ip address
 $WSSN=ip address
 $WSSP=80
 Surrogate-Capability=WS-ESI="ESI/1.0+"
 _WS_HAPRT_WLMVERSION=-1

Comment: I believe Luiggi was looking for more information in the stack trace itself. It would be odd for that to be *all* the information available.

Comment: This is the header message, it throws the FTL error while evealuating the expression. i am clueless to this.

Comment: Jon/Luiggi rest it goes from some files to get that value
I think its some problem with the JDK version or something ? But I am not sure.

Comment: You get the exception when the request is executed. That exception prints a stacktrace in the server log files. We want to see that long message to try to understand the problem.

Comment: Luiggi and Jon

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602565/scriptenginemanager-giving-ftl-error